# Binding request failed in MPC

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

```
#import "Session.h"
#import <MultipeerConnectivity/MultipeerConnectivity.h>

@interface Session () <MCSessionDelegate,MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic) MCSession *session;
@property (strong,nonatomic) MCAdvertiserAssistant *advertiser;
@property (strong,nonatomic) MCPeerID *peerId;
@end

@implementation Session

#pragma mark - Initialiser(s)

//Setting the name of the peer
-(id)initWithDisplayName:(NSString *)name{
    self = [super init];
    self.peerId = [[MCPeerID alloc]initWithDisplayName:name];
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Property accessor(s)

//Late initialisation
-(MCSession *)session{
    if(!_session){
        _session = [[MCSession alloc]initWithPeer:self.peerId securityIdentity:nil encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionNone];
        _session.delegate = self;
    }
    return _session;
}

#pragma mark - MCSessionDelegate Methods

//Detecting the change in the connection state of the peer
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state{
    if (state == MCSessionStateConnecting) {
        NSLog(@"Connecting to %@", peerID.displayName);
    } else if (state == MCSessionStateConnected) {
        NSLog(@"Connected to %@", peerID.displayName);
    } else if (state == MCSessionStateNotConnected) {
        NSLog(@"Disconnected from %@", peerID.displayName);
    }
}

//Handling the data recieved by the session
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID{
    [self.delegate session:self didRecieveData:data];
}

//Handling the stream recieved by the session
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveStream:(NSInputStream *)stream withName:(NSString *)streamName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID{
    [self.delegate session:self didRecieveAudioStream:stream];
}

//Started recieving stream
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didStartReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withProgress:(NSProgress *)progress{

}

//Finished recieving stream
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didFinishReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID atURL:(NSURL *)localURL withError:(NSError *)error{

}

-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveCertificate:(NSArray *)certificate fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID certificateHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))certificateHandler{
    certificateHandler(YES);
    NSLog(@"Recieved a certificate");
}

#pragma mark - MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate methods

//Browser view controller has completd
-(void)browserViewControllerDidFinish:(MCBrowserViewController *)browserViewController{
    [browserViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

//Browser view controller is cancelled
-(void)browserViewControllerWasCancelled:(MCBrowserViewController *)browserViewController{
    [browserViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Advertising and Browsing

//Initialise the browser
-(MCBrowserViewController *)browserViewControllerForServiceType:(NSString *)type{
    MCBrowserViewController *browser = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc]initWithServiceType:type session:self.session];
    browser.delegate = self;
    return browser;
}

//Starting the advertiser for the particular service type
-(void)startAdvertisingForServiceType:(NSString *)type discoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    if(!self.advertiser)
        self.advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc]initWithServiceType:type discoveryInfo:info session:self.session];
    [self.advertiser start];
}

//Stoping the advertiser
-(void)stopAdvertising{
    [self.advertiser stop];
}

#pragma mark - Misc methods

//Creating the output stream in the current session
-(NSOutputStream *)outputStreamForPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerId{
    NSError *error;
    NSOutputStream *stream = [self.session startStreamWithName:@"Music" toPeer:peerId error:&error];
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error userInfo].description);
    return stream;
}

//Sending the date to all the peers connected to the session
-(void)sendData:(NSData *)data{
    NSError * error;
    [self.session sendData:data toPeers:self.session.connectedPeers withMode:MCSessionSendDataUnreliable error:&error];
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error userInfo].description);
}

-(NSArray *)connectedPeers{
    return [self.session connectedPeers];
}
@end
```

This is my session file in mpc. The error that i am getting is

Project[7347:876615] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [12ECD777] on channel [0].
and

Project[7347:876615] [ViceroyTrace] [ICE][ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (317511543)

Project[7347:876751] [ViceroyTrace] [ICE][ERROR]    Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).

Need help

Comment: If more information is needed tell me

Comment: I am using a class called MPC which is in ios. So it is also available in swift. Tats why i thought swift people might help too @EricAya

Answer (score 0):

I've faced these problems some time ago and it ended up that I had done 2 mistakes:

1. Never, ever, copy a `MCPeerID` object: Once I was storing `MCPeerID` objects that I received in `MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate`'s `foundPeer` calls as the key of a Dictionary, which copied the object. Then when later I used that peer ID to invite a peer via `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` the connection would fail because the `MCPeerID` was a copy.
2. If one of your devices is a iOS Simulator, make sure your firewall is not blocking external connections at the OS level.

I feel your pain... MCFramework logs don't help. 
I hope this can help. Good luck.